# How can i correctly unregister a receiver out of another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, reference, broadcastreceiver

i got trouble unregistering my receiver out of another activity. here it is:

Starting/Register the BroadcastReceiver in my launching Activity A.

**Activity A:**

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
   private PowerButtonReceiver mPowerButtonReceiver = null;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      if (getPowerButtonReceiver() == null)
      {
            mPowerButtonReceiver(new PowerButtonReceiver());                                            
            registerReceiver(mPowerButtonReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"));
      }         
   }

public void unregister() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mPowerButtonReceiver);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    if (mPowerButtonReceiver == null) {
        Log.i(TAG,"unregistered PowerButtonReceiver!");
    }       
}
```

then i start Activity B inside the onReceive()-method of my receiver.
After this i step into the onCreate()-method of Activity B, do my stuff and at the end of onCreate() i want to unregister the BroadcastReceiver:

**Activity B:**  (--> android:launchMode="singleTop")

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);       

    [...do my stuff...]

//un-register PowerButtonReceiver --> call in Activity A

    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
    m.getParent();
    m.unregister();         
}
```

my last line starts the call for unregister(), but there the Receiver is null and it looks like it is not getting the reference for it. Also the Receiver does not get unregistered and is still listening. I am pretty sure that my error is in doi9ng the reference/call; but i don't get how to do it right :/

What am i missing here? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your Activity A context to Activity B through intent.putExtra() method . Then instead of doing  `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();` do `MainActivity m =  ((MainActivity)(passedContext));`.

Comment: the intent for launching Activity B is within my receiver-class. there is no context of activity A!?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something like this succesfully, see if this helps: I have a HeadSetTesTActivity , a Headsetconnectorreciever, ActivityB.
**HEADSETTESTACTIVITY.JAVA**
       `public class HeadsettestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Headsetconnectorreciever r;

```
static HeadsettestActivity activity;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    activity=this;
    Log.d("Inside activity ", "before broadcast reciever registered");
    r = new Headsetconnectorreciever();
    registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
    Log.d("Inside activity ", "after broadcast reciever registered");
}
public  void unregister() {
    try {
        if(r!=null){
            unregisterReceiver(r);
            Log.i("HeadsettestActivity","Inside unregister ");
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    if (r == null) {
        Log.i("HeadsettestActivity","unregistered PowerButtonReceiver!");
    }
}
```

}`

**Headsetconnectorreciever**
`public class Headsetconnectorreciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
     private boolean headsetConnected = false;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Inside broadcast reciever ", "Inside onrecieve");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.hasExtra("state")){
         Log.d("Inside broadcast reciever ", "hasstate");
           if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
            headsetConnected = false;
            Log.d("Inside broadcast reciever ", "disconnected");
           Toast.makeText(context, "Headset is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
           else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
               Log.d("Inside broadcast reciever ", "disconnected");
            headsetConnected = true;
            Intent intent2=new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
            context.startActivity(intent2);

           }
    }
}
```

}`

and finally my **ACTIVITY B**

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Headset is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    HeadsettestActivity a = HeadsettestActivity.activity ;
    a.unregister();


}
```

}

The code actually worked.

Comment: i figured, that you can unregister the receiver inside the onReceive(). Works fine :-)

Comment: Ohk I thought , you might have to do some explicit jobs in activityB and then only you want to unregister.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not closing the other activity i would had sent intent to Activity A,

Activity B

```
boolean unregister = true;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("unregister",unregister);
startActivity(intent);
```

on Activity A you override onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("unregister", false)) {
            unregister();

        }

    }

}
```